# If f(x) is a function such that...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)$ is a function such that $f(x) + f''(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = f^2(x) + f'^2(x)$ and $g(3) = 8$, then find $g(8)$.

Comment: I first tried to integrate the equation of f(x) + f"(x)=0. I took the help of given data that g(3)=8. I put x=3 in the equation of g and found the value of f'(x) in terms of f(x) for x equal to 3. I put x=3 in the integrated equation and substituted f'(x) in terms of f(x) so that I can do something about constant term obtained in integration. But after this I had two unknowns and no data. I had f(x) and also a constant term unknown. So I couldn't solve it after that. And yah! Its correct answer is 8 but I'm not able to bring it to the end.

Comment: Do you know how to solve ordinary differential equations?

Answer (score 11):

You have that $ g'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)+2f'(x)f''(x)=2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))=0 $. Therefore $ g $ is constant and since you know that $ g(3)=8 $ it follows that $ g(x)=8 $ for any $ x $ so in particular $ g(8)=8 $.

Comment: Thank you! Nice thinking

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Compute $g'$.
$
% filler space
$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$f(x)=C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x)$$